# FFmpeg. Как записать программно поток в реальном режиме?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь записать поток кадров, который в будущем будет как захват данных с устройства. Сейчас для теста сделал захват кадров с экрана. Дело вот в чём. Если нумерация кадров идёт последовательно, то ffmpeg честно пишет в результирующий файл - 25 кадров в сек. Но у меня будет реальный режим, значит какие-то кадры будут пропадать.

Я сымитировал этот случай как увеличение счётчика на каждом шаге на 2. И, конечно, файл пишет - 12,5 к/с. А должно быть 25 к/с.

Подскажите какой параметр установить, что не так делаю?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C"
{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavutil/avassert.h>
    #include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
    #include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
    #include <libswresample/swresample.h>
    #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}

using namespace std;

// Для av_err2str
#ifdef  __cplusplus
static const std::string av_make_error_string(int errnum)
{
    char errbuf[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    av_strerror(errnum, errbuf, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE);
    return (std::string)errbuf;
}

#undef av_err2str
#define av_err2str(errnum) av_make_error_string(errnum).c_str()
#endif // __cplusplus

#define STREAM_DURATION   10.0
#define STREAM_FRAME_RATE 25 /* 25 images/s */
#define STREAM_PIX_FMT  AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA // AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA AV_PIX_FMT_ARGB
#define CODEC_PIX_FMT  AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P //AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P AV_PIX_FMT_NV12 AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P  AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24

#define FRAME_WIDTH 1440
#define FRAME_HEIGHT 900

#define SCALE_FLAGS SWS_BICUBIC

AVCodecContext *cc = NULL;
AVFormatContext *oc = NULL;
AVOutputFormat *fmt = NULL;
AVDictionary *opt = NULL;

AVCodec *video_codec = NULL;
AVStream *video_stream = NULL;

AVFrame *video_frame = NULL;

int64_t next_pts = 0;

SwsContext *sws_ctx = 0;

static AVFrame *alloc_picture(enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height)
{
    AVFrame *picture;
    int ret;

    picture = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!picture)
        return NULL;

    picture->format = pix_fmt;
    picture->width = width;
    picture->height = height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(picture, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate frame data.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return picture;
}

bool bInit = false;
int nSimpleWidth = FRAME_WIDTH; 
int nSimpleHeight = FRAME_HEIGHT;
int nSimpleStride = 0;
int nSimpleAlign = 0;
int bSimpleUseAlign = 0;
HWND hDesktopWnd;
HDC hDesktopDC;
HDC hCaptureDC;

int cadrSize = 0;
BITMAPINFO m_bmiSimple;
int m_bSimpleBottomUpImg = 0;
BYTE *m_bSimpleData = 0;

HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = 0;
BOOL res = 0;

LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;
int startFrame = 0;
int frameCounter = 0;
int ofps = 40; 
int globalStat = 0;

static AVFrame *get_video_frame()
{
    if (av_compare_ts(next_pts, cc->time_base, STREAM_DURATION, AVRational{ 1, 1 }) >= 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (av_frame_make_writable(video_frame) < 0)
        exit(1);

    if (!bInit)
    {
        /**
    * Настройка захвата кадра.
    **/
    }

    if (bInit)
    {
        BOOL res = BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, nSimpleWidth, nSimpleHeight, hDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
        if (cc->pix_fmt != STREAM_PIX_FMT)
        {
            sws_scale(sws_ctx, &m_bSimpleData, &nSimpleStride, 0, cc->height, video_frame->data, video_frame->linesize);

        }
        else
        {
            memcpy_s(video_frame->data[0], cadrSize, m_bSimpleData, cadrSize);
        }
    }

    if (!startFrame)
    {
        startFrame = 1;
        frameCounter = 0;
        next_pts = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // Расчёт времени.
        //++frameCounter;
        frameCounter += 2; // Emulate skip frame.

    }

    // Ставим время кадра.
    //ost->frame->pts = ost->next_pts++;
    next_pts = frameCounter;
    video_frame->pts = next_pts;
    cout << "pts: " << video_frame->pts << endl;

    ++globalStat;
    return video_frame;
}

static int write_frame(AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, const AVRational *time_base, AVStream *st, AVPacket *pkt)
{
    av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, *time_base, st->time_base);
    pkt->stream_index = st->index;

    return av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, pkt);
}

static int write_video_frame()
{
    int ret;
    int ret1;
    int flush = 0;
    AVFrame *frame;
    int got_packet = 0;
    AVPacket pkt = { 0 };

    frame = get_video_frame();

    av_init_packet(&pkt);

    ret = avcodec_send_frame(cc, frame);

    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a frame for video encoding\n");
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error eagain\n");
        }
        else if (ret == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            flush = 1;
            fprintf(stderr, "Error EOF\n");
        }
        else if (ret == AVERROR(EINVAL))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error EINVAL\n");
        }
        else if (ret == AVERROR(ENOMEM))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error ENOMEM\n");
        }

        if (ret != AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    while (flush || ret >= 0) {
        got_packet = 1;
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(cc, &pkt);

    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            got_packet = 0;
            flush = 0;
            break;
        }
        else if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error during encoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        ret1 = write_frame(oc, &cc->time_base, video_stream, &pkt);
        if (ret1 < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing video frame: %s\n",
                av_err2str(ret1));
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return (frame || got_packet) ? 0 : 1;
}

// Обработка.
int process()
{
    int ret = 0;
    const char *filename = "D:\\capture_test.mp4";

    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc, NULL, NULL, filename);
    if (!oc) 
    {
        cout << "Couldnt open file in format." << endl;
        avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc, NULL, "mpeg", filename);
    }
    if (!oc)
    {
        cout << "Couldnt open file in MPEG format." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    fmt = oc->oformat;

    if (fmt->video_codec == AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) 
    {
        cout << "Video codec dont podderzjka." << endl;
    }

    video_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(fmt->video_codec);
    if (!video_codec)
    {
        cout << "Could not find encoder for " << avcodec_get_name(fmt->video_codec) << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    video_stream = avformat_new_stream(oc, NULL);
    if (!video_stream) 
    {
        cout << "Could not allocate stream" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    video_stream->id = oc->nb_streams - 1;
    video_stream->avg_frame_rate = AVRational{ 1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE };

    cc = avcodec_alloc_context3(video_codec);
    if (!cc) 
    {
        cout << "Could not alloc an encoding context" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cc->codec_id = video_codec->id;
    cc->bit_rate = 400000;
    cc->width = FRAME_WIDTH;
    cc->height = FRAME_HEIGHT;
    cc->gop_size = 12;
    cc->pix_fmt = CODEC_PIX_FMT;
    if (cc->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) 
    {   
        cc->max_b_frames = 2;
    }
    if (cc->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) 
    {
        cc->mb_decision = 2;
    }

    video_stream->time_base = AVRational{ 1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE };
    cc->time_base = video_stream->time_base;

    if (fmt->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) cc->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    video_frame = alloc_picture(cc->pix_fmt, cc->width, cc->height);
    if (!video_frame) 
    {
        cout << "Could not allocate video frame" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Открываем кодек.
    ret = avcodec_open2(cc, video_codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) 
    {
        cout << "Could not open video codec: " << av_err2str(ret) << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    /* copy the stream parameters to the muxer */
    ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(video_stream->codecpar, cc);
    if (ret < 0) 
    {
        cout << "Could not copy the stream parameters" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    av_dump_format(oc, 0, filename, 1);

    /* open the output file, if needed */
    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) 
    {
        ret = avio_open(&oc->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) 
        {
            cout << "Could not open " << filename << " : " << av_err2str(ret) << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    ret = avformat_write_header(oc, &opt);
    if (ret < 0) 
    {
        cout << "Error occurred when opening output file: " << av_err2str(ret) << endl;
        return 0;
    }


    // Пишем данные.
    int encode_video = 1;
    while (encode_video)
    {
        cout << "Thread video 1" << endl;
        encode_video = !write_video_frame();
    }


    // Закрываем.
    av_write_trailer(oc);

    /* Close each codec. */
    avcodec_free_context(&cc);

    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        avio_closep(&oc->pb);
    }

    /* free the stream */
    avformat_free_context(oc);


    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    process();

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему какие-то кадры должны пропадать?

Comment: Ну даже если какие-то кадры почему-то пропадают, next_pts должен быть последовательным, то есть на каждый новый кадр должно быть next_pts++ - ведь кодеру фиолетово, что вы где-то потеряли какие-то изображения, он будет кодировать кадры последовательно,  по мере их подачи в стстему

Comment: Чтобы кадры не пропадали заведите очередь типа FIFO - с одного конца подавайте кадр, с другого берите, кодируйте и добавляйте в выходной контейнер. Для этого лучше использовать отдельные потоки - один получает кадр и добавляет в очередь, другой - берет с головы очереди очередной кадр, кодирует его и пишет в контейнер

Comment: @AlexanderChernin . Допустим, у меня каждые 40 мс формируется кадр (25 к/с). На его сжатие уходит процессорное время. Если первый кадр я получил в 0 мс., на сжатие ушло скажем 80 мс, то след. кадр, в реальном времени мне нужно брать в 80 мс, а не в 40 мс. Значит pts для первого кадра я указал 0, потом для след. кадра (взятый на 80 мс) pts = 2. Таким образом pts=1 пропущен.

Comment: Нет, pts должен быть последовательным, это раз. Второе, я вам описал схему как кодировать все кадры - воспользуйтесь очередью и двумя потоками, так вы не потеряете ни одного кадра

Comment: @AlexanderChernin тогда подскажите, пожалуйста, как кодировать, если кадры могут пропускаться. Ваша схема с очередью мне не подходит, буфер рано или поздно заполнится.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте посмотрим на картинку последовательной обработки (у нас кодирования) кадра.

[image: процесс декодинга]

Здесь цифрами обозначены:

1. Буфер, или источник живого кадра/изображения
2. Считыватель данных из внешнего источника
3. Кодировщик во внутренний формат (сжатие)
4. Рекордер (запись данных)

Слева от красной линии находится то, что нам неподвластно - буфер в памяти сетевой карты, или источника изображения, например, камеры и тому подобное.

Вы можете подключить включенную камеру к компьютеру и она будет считывать кадры со своей матрицы, при этом, либо сохраняя их в своем буфере, а в случае необходимости, перетирая старые, при этом внешнее устройство, или программа должны будут заботиться о сборе этих данных (с точки зрения вашей программы это активный режим), либо сразу передавая их по каналам передачи данных приемнику и тогда о сохранении и обработке кадров должна заботиться программа, или устройство на другом конце кабеля (пассивный режим).

Допустим у вас синхронный (последовательный) алгоритм сбора и обработки получаемых кадров/изображений, следовательно, пока ваш алгоритм полностью не пробежит по всем стадиям обработки изображения, он не будет готов считать и обработать новый кадр от внешнего источника данных, соответственно, если частота, или производительность внешнего источника выше, чем производительность вашей программы, то он (внешний источник) будет просто перетирать старые кадры новыми.

Теперь обратимся к кодировщику (цифра 3). Большинство алгоритмов кодирования для сжатия данных используют группы кадров, причем бывает, что не только предыдущие, но и последующие (погуглите пакетизация IPBB). Соответственно, на вход кодировщик принимает кадры с последовательной временной меткой pts (presentation timestamp, в единицах AVRational), используя которую, формирует последовательность сжатых кадров (в ffmpeg это AVPacket) с временной меткой dts (decoding timestamp), а по-сути формируя последовательность IPBB, где B - означает bidirectional, то есть двунаправленный кадр, который может брать данные как в прошлом, там и в будущем, поэтому последовательность PTS и DTS могут не совпадать!

Кодировщику совершенно фиолетово, что какой-то внешний источник данных перетирает старые данные новыми, ему надо закодировать связанную последовательность сжатых пакетов, поэтому (я так думаю) pts должен быть последовательным.

Разница между pts двух соседних кадров для "сырых данных", если их перевести из AVRational в миллисекунды будет равна 1 сек / fps (частоту кадров в секунду). 
Соответственно, при частоте 25 кадров в секунду это 40 миллисекунд, что вы и указываете при инициализации кодировщика выходного контейнера.

Теперь вернемся к вашей виртуальной проблеме, - потеря кадров. Если ваше синхронное, последовательное приложение работает медленнее, чем источник кадров, то тут ничего не поделаешь (либо оптимизируйте код, или купите другое железо).

Есть другой вариант, старый проверенный способ сбора высокочастотных данных из сети - асинхронное приложение (этот вариант работал с высокочастотными протоколами еще на первых PC, а может быть и раньше, но эта информация покрыта туманом).

В нем между цифрами 2 и 3 находится буфер-очередь типа FIFO для сбора кадров AVFrame (в случает кодирования), между цифрами 3 и 4 находится буфер-очередь типа FIFO для кадров AVPacket - сжатых кадров, готовых для записи. При этом, цифра 2 это поток получения данных из внешнего источника, на выходе он подсовывает эти данных в буфер-очередь 2-3. Цифра 3 - это поток кодировщика, на входе он берет данные из буфера 2-3, кодирует их и сохраняет в буфер-очередь 3-4. Цифра 4 - это поток записи сжатых кадров в выходной файл, который на входе берет данные из буфера 3-4. В такой реализации вероятность потери кадров остается, но по сравнению с синхронным вариант эта цифра крайне мала.

*Небольшой вывод и комментарий на счет "ну, нет больше памяти, а кадр пришел".*

Повторюсь, при последовательном (синхронном) процессе получения и обработки кадров очередной кадр не придет просто так и память не займет (пришедший кадр будет помещен в буфер сетевой карты, например, и если там что-то уже было и места уже нет, то это что-то просто затрется). Мы получим очередной кадр только тогда, когда отработаем текущий, соответственно в таком режиме работы память у нас занимает только один кадр - тот который мы сейчас обрабатываем и это никак не влияет ни на какие настройки ffmpeg.

Кодировщик кодека контейнера может ждать очередной кадр бесконечно долго, но получив его, будет ожидать, что его pts будет последовательным, что я описал ранее. Последовательность его нарушать нельзя, потому что таким образом нарушится процесс кодирования и формирования последовательности сжатых кадров AVPacket с соответствующими dts.

Свой ответ я хочу проиллюстрировать вот [этим наглядным пособием работы последовательного алгоритма обработки и записи кадров в файл](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46QaOikFYhM). Тут, конечно, нет перетирания данных в буфере, потому что абсолютно все работает последовательно, а для машины записи нет никаких особых настроек )). Обратите внимание, работа происходит с одним кадром! :)

p.s. При асинхронной обработке полученных кадров действительно может прийти много кадров и памяти может не хватить, но во-первых, перед решением таких критических задач мы должны это предусмотреть, а во-вторых, предвидя это, выбрать правильные инструменты, а именно, в качестве буферов-очередей FIFО выбрать циклические с регулируемой емкостью, чтобы не превысить критический уровень памяти. В таких ситуациях одни кадры тоже могут быть затерты другими, но опять же, это никак не будет влиять на настройки кодека, который все также будет ожидать последовательный pts!

Вот, как-то так )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Описали вы, конечно, хорошо (за это +), но на конкретный вопрос (что отбрасывать и какие параметры крутить, если кадры пропадают (ну, нет больше памяти, а кадр пришел)) все же не ответили.

Comment: @avp ответ дан более чем полный (тема не простая, но по-моему я все разжевал и даже частично предварительно переварил, как пингвин, возвращающийся с рыбалки), но дополнительно добавил вывод  с иллюстрациями :)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin , много написали, теория хороша. Дело в контейнере, если писать в avi, то он запишет установленные 25 кадров в секунду, а с mp4 не так. Не знаете в чём дело?

Comment: @Ivan Sh. Контейнер не имеет значения, дело в кодеке. Смотрите настройки кодека, название и другие характеристики

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, вот иллюстрация в точку, как раз под мою погонялу в определенных кругах -- Полковник